# Stream processing on a file on ftp

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

In one of the application, our client receives multiple events in files, uploaded on ftp server. Frequency of these files will be in minutes. These events need to be process individually.

One way of processing these events is to push them to kafka and then using kafka streams/consumer process them one by one. Is this the right approach or we should think about some batch process like spark? We don't expect more than 10K of message in worst case every minute.

Thanks

Comment: How large are these files? Kafka is not meant for **file** processing. By default, the message limit is only 1MB

Comment: We are planning to read file using program/Kafka connector, push messages to Kafka cluster and then process using Kafka stream/consumer.

Comment: If you're reading the files line by line, or have some other delimiter, then Spark or a regular Kafka producer will work fine (assuming you don't want to know which lines come from which file). What issues are you having with either approach?

Comment: We dont want to introduce spark complexity for this use case as we are not going to do any analytics. This will be complex event processing on individual event. We are not facing any issue with this approach. I just wanted to check if I am missing any trick.

Comment: The only thing I can think of would be how do you handle errors in the middle of a file? Do you read the entire file from the beginning and get duplicate events or just skip the file completely? Similarly, are you always reading the whole FTP directory, and if so, how are you preventing any file from being read more than once?

Comment: We will use S3 (over aws) with integration with ftp. S3 will trigger an event whenever a new file is written to s3. A lambda function will be fired that will read all the data from file line by line and push it to kafka (along with source-file name). Once data is received in kafka, all processing (including validation) take place here.

Comment: Okay, even there though, a lambda could fail mid-file... Just something to think about